# R: Weighted Bootstrap in R

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

I am familiar with the general bootstrap procedure (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics):

- Suppose you have a dataset of size "n"
- Take a random sample with replacement of size "n"
- Take the mean of this random sample
- Repeat the above steps many times

**My Question:**  I am interested in extending this to the "weighted bootstrap" - that is, now each observation has an associated probability of being selected.

Here is my attempt to write the R code for this:

```
  # function to calculate the weighted mean (inputs: data x and weights w)

    weighted_mean <- function(x, w) {
      sum(x * w) / sum(w)
    }
    
    # function that performs random sampling with replacement where the probability of selecting any point is proportional to the assigned weight (inputs: R is the number of bootstrap repetitions) 

  
    weighted_bootstrap <- function(data, weights, R) {   
      estimates <- numeric(R)  
      for (i in seq_len(R)) {
        bootstrap_sample <- sample(data, size = length(data), replace = TRUE, prob = weights)
        estimates[i] <- weighted_mean(bootstrap_sample, weights)
      }
      estimates
    }
```

Here is how this weighted bootstrap function would be used on some data (note that the weights must add to 1) :

```
  data <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
        weights <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2)
        R <- 1000
        estimates <- weighted_bootstrap(data, weights, R)
        plot(hist(estimates))
```

**Can someone please tell me if I have understood this correctly?**
Thanks!

Comment: hi stats_noob! thanks for your question. Similar to your question from a few days ago, it's unclear to me what the question is- either you're asking if your code is correct, in which case, it belongs on Code Review, or you're asking if your mathematics is correct, in which case it belongs on Cross Validated. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way it is currently implemented you are using weights twice.
First in the `sample()`function. There it is correct.
And then once again for the `weighted_mean()` function. This one will produce wrong results as the weight vector does not change and therefore e.g. the fifth weight will always be used to weigh the fifth observation in your bootstrap sample.

Therefore, to achieve what you want to do the code would be:

```
weighted_bootstrap <- function(data, weights, R) {   
  estimates <- numeric(R)  
  for (i in seq_len(R)) {
    bootstrap_sample <- sample(data, size = length(data), replace = TRUE, prob = weights)
    estimates[i] <- mean(bootstrap_sample)
  }
  return(estimates)
}

data <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
weights <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2)
R <- 1000
estimates <- weighted_bootstrap(data, weights, R)
hist(estimates)
```